# Need to create a common function for axios .then and catch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my controller.js code

```
action = dispatch(userValidateOtp(api_url, API_METHODS.PUT, pData))

  return action.then((data) => {
    return data
  }).catch((reason) => {
    try {
      return reason.response.data
    } catch (error) {
      history.push('/error')
      return false
    }
  })
```

I want common function for this return i tried async and await

Error: = **cannot read property 'then' of undefined react axios - Google Search**

util.js

```
export const axiosCall = (reason, history) => {
return action.then(function (data) {
 return data;
 }).catch((reason) => {
 try {
   return reason.response.data
 } catch (err) {
   console.log("demo", err);
   history.push('/error')
   return false
}
})
}
```

**called function** : axiosCall(action , history);

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :-

```
import axios from 'axios'

async function callApi() { 
   const data = await withTryCatch(
     axios.get('https://random.dog/woof.json')
    );
   console.log(data)
}

async function withTryCatch(apiCall) {
   try {
     console.log('inside the withTryCa')
      const { data } = await apiCall;
      return data;
   } catch(err) {
     console.log("demo", err);
    //  history.push('/error')
     return false
   }
}
```

Comment: no i am getting error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
"

Comment: i have done this      generate: async ({ username, userSegment }) => {
        const data = await withTryCatch(dispatch(userGenerate(api_url, API_METHODS.POST, pData))); }
output: return data = 'undefined'

Comment: where are you .thening?

Comment: when this function is called from controller.generate({ ...creds, segment }).then((data) => {